# Table 'stock1.products1' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a database and table. Here's the code for db and table creation :

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//connect to mysql
$db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '') or die ('Unable to Connect.Check your connection parameters');
//create the main database if it doesn't already exists
$query = 'CREATE DATABASE stock1';
mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
//make sure our recently created db is the active one
mysql_select_db('stock1', $db) or die (mysql_error($db));

//create the products table
$query = 'CREATE TABLE products1(
         product_id     INTEGER UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
         product_name   VARCHAR(40)         NOT NULL,
         product_stock  SMALLINT UNSIGNED   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

         PRIMARY KEY(product_id)
         )';

         echo "Success";

         ?>
```

After this, I create a file which accepts 2 inputs and then transmits this data to a php file.
Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Inventory - Backend</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="addproducts.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Product Name : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="pname"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product Quantity : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="productq"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Add Product"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the backed:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '') or die ('Unable to Connect.Check your connection parameters');
mysql_select_db('stock1', $db) or die (mysql_error($db));

$productname=$_POST['pname'];
$productquantity=$_POST['productq'];

$query = 'INSERT INTO products1
          (product_id, product_name, product_stock)
          VALUES
          (NULL, "' . $productname . '", ' . $productquantity . ')';

          mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
          echo "Product Added";
          ?>
```

But, when I try to run this script, I get this error:

```
Table 'stock1.products1' doesn't exist
```

Can anyone tell me why this error appears?  And how I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe it means that the table stock1.products1 doesn't exist? Note that you aren't actually executing the query that would create it.

Comment: go to phpMyAdmin and check 2 things:
-is your database called "stock1"?
-if yes, check if there is a table called "products1".

Comment: This is a good exercise in debugging 101.  Actually try to LOOK at your DB to see what's going on.  Also, you really need to add some security and error checking to your code.  Blindly accepting input, especially without escaping it, is just begging for your system to be compromised

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by missing a query execution. Therefore: Too Localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to execute your query which creates table:

```
$query = 'CREATE TABLE products1(
         product_id     INTEGER UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
         product_name   VARCHAR(40)         NOT NULL,
         product_stock  SMALLINT UNSIGNED   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

         PRIMARY KEY(product_id)
         )';

mysql_query($query);

echo "Success";
```

The line `mysql_query($query);` is missing in your code.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing

```
mysql_query($query);
```

before your `echo "Success";` your `products1` table has not been created.

Answer (score 0):

You never executed the query that creates the products table.